# SQL Server 2014 services are not visible

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

I've installed the SQL Server [MgmtStudio 64BIT\SQLManagementStudio_x64_ENU.exe](https://www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/confirmation.aspx?id=42299) . I tried to login in the SSMS but it throws an error specifying "Network Path Not Found.". After googling I found to start the services.

But, in my services I couldn't even find the list of SQL services as show in the below image.

[image: Missing SQL services]

I even checked the sql server configuration and everything is enabled.

This is my first time installation in Windows 10 64 bit.

Please provide if this might be a duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

I think you installed only the management studio client. Please install the Server version of SQL Server

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=42299